# Rails has_many but only one model per 30 days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to restrict an `appuser` to only have one `lead` per 30 days.

I know you can do conditions in the has_many. So I want to do something like this:

```
class Appuser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :leads, -> { where created_at: created_at > leads.last.created_at + 30.days }
end
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas how to adjust the `has_many` conditions to ensure a new lead isn't created for at least 30 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do this with a custom validation and not the way you are trying to do it.

Something along the lines of:

```
validate :past_30_days, :on => :create

 def past_30_days
   if created_at < leads.last.created_at + 30.days
     errors.add(:leads, "need to have at least 30 days of separation.")
   end
 end
```

This will prevent the new record from being created for that person if one already exists within the last 30 days.

Comment: Question - would you put this in the Lead model or the Appuser model?

Comment: The validation goes on the Lead model because this is what you are checking against before creating another one. That said, you will need to change the condition `created_at < leads.last.created_at + 30.days` to accommodate for it being the in the Lead model. In your lead model if you have your association correctly `belongs_to :app_user` you should have access to app_user so you can check the app_user.leads.last etc. Hope that helps.

Comment: I have edited there to get valid leads by appuser_id by adding `last_lead = where(appuser_id: self.appuser_id).last` so you can change your condition into `created_at < last_lead.created_at + 30.days`. Hopefully, it help you.

Comment: Thanks guys! This is great!